# Allowing to create multiple entries only on internal service calls

Tags: mongodb, feathersjs

I want to create multiple entries on an internal service call. But for external transports (rest, websockets) this functionality should still be blocked.

I know that the multi option can be set to true or ['create'] in the service options but this does not fix the problem, because external transports could then create multiple entries.

My first solutions was this:

someService.hooks.js

```
...
before: {
  create: [
    context => {
      if (!context.params.provider) {
        context.service.options.multi = true;
      }
      return context;
    }
  ],
}
...
```

But this completely overwrites the service options for all service calls.

The only other solutions I came up with, is to set service.multi to true and validate each external service call with a hook.

Would this be the only solution which would work or did I missed something?

Comment: You could have a `before` hook that checks if `context.data` is an array when the provider is set (e.g. an external call) and throw an error in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can currently do is enable `multi: [ 'create' ]` and check in a hook if it is an external call and throw an error for arrays in that case:

```
const { BadRequest } = require('@feathersjs/errors');
// ...
  create: [
    async context => {
      if (context.params.provider && Array.isArray(context.data)) {
        throw new BadRequest('Not allowed');
      }

      return context;
    }
  ],
```

In upcoming versions this will be possible by just passing the `multi` option in `params` (tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/databases/issues/8))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm seeing forward to use `{ multi: true }` for internal service calls which would make this much easier :).

Comment: Just make sure your hooks account for data possibly being an array.  It's an easy thing to forget (and have before hooks assume `context.data` is a single item)